# How do I check if the user is the new user or not in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

```
<?php
    $facebook = new Facebook(array("appId"=>'xxxxxx', "secret"=> 'xxxxxxxx'));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                     'redirect_uri'=>'apps.facebook.com/abc/'));
        header("Location:$loginUrl");
    }
?>
```

How do I check if the user is the new user or not? Earlier, Facebook used to provide `installed = 1` in the URL. Now, how do I check if the user is the new user or not?

Answer (score 0):

An API call to `/me/?fields=installed` will tell you if the current user has installed your app - if you need to know if the user has never used the app before, you should probably keep this state in your own app

Comment: well i want to know if the user has landed into app by clicking on authorize button or not .. is there any way to know it?

Comment: earlier ?installed=1 used to come in the URL if the user land to app by clicking on authorization

Comment: Is this in the old oauth 1 auth flows? You still get to choose the post-auth URL with oauth 2 - just send all logins to the same endpoint and show different content if it's a new user